# Why do we say a tree graph has one face?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

There is no cycle in the tree, so there can't be any "region that is bounded by a cycle".

There is also no way to "bore a hole into one of the faces and expand it" as there is no 3D figure to start with.

Either definition for face would not apply in the case of a tree. But still, it's regarded as having one face. Why?

Comment: The faces are the regions the graph subdivides the plane into. There's only one region ("the outside"), but it's there.

Comment: ...and in general the boundary of a face needs only to be a closed walk.